# How to call multiple variable of string with numbering in loop?

Tags: java, string, loops, variables

What i am trying to achieve is, let's say I've these variables below:

```
String num1 = "blah1";
String num2 = "blah2";
String num3 = "blah3";
String num4 = "blah4";
String num5 = "blah5";
```

Now i want to create a single string variable which would iterate the all values of string's variable inside loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<=5; i++){
   System.out.println(num+""+i); //I know, this would give me some errors. But i want to make something like this to call all string variables.
}
```

Here i want to print all the values of string's variable by using loop, How to achieve this?

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to use an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Add them to an array or a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a use case for an *array*:

```
String nums[] = new String[] {
    "blah1",
    "blah2",
    "blah3",
    "blah4",
    "blah5"
}
```

And then you can easily iterate through the values (note that you don't need to duplicate the number of elements (5) ):

```
for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(nums[i]);
}
```

[More about arrays in the Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

---

Alternatively, you may use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an Array - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

An Array is a container containing a fixed number of values that are the same type, eg:

```
String [] nums = new String[5];
```

The above line creates a array called nums of type String which can hold 5 individual String values (they are initially null).

Another way to declare this would be to use:

```
String [] alt_nums = {"blah1","blah2","blah3","blah4","blah5"};
```

This set's each value stored in alt_nums to a specific value as declared in the curly braces.

To iterate through an Array you can use an iterative for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < alt_nums.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(alt_nums[i]);
}
```

or you can use an enhanced for loop which does this automatically.

```
for(String num : alt_nums) {
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use java 8:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("sad", "asdf");
strings.forEach(str -> System.out.println(str));
```